# Regex to only match specific characters preceded by a space or nothing (start of line)

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following tweets:

```
RT @username This is my tweet
Check this! RT @username This is my tweet
I have PART 2 downloaded
```

In a `preg_replace()` call, I am using regex to replace the `RT` (common *retweet* syntax) with `{RT}`. It almost works, however, it also matches `RT` in `PART` in the last tweet:

- `I have PART 2 downloaded` becomes `I have PA{RT} 2 downloaded`

I want the regex to only allow **nothing** (beginning of string) or a **space (U+0020)** in front of `RT`.

The current `preg_replace()` call:

```
echo preg_replace("(\RT(?=\s)/", '{RT}', $tweet);
```

Comment: Forget to add the regex to the question?

Comment: Added new `preg_replace()` call to my answer that should work for ya :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `(^|[ ])` before `RT` in your regex to match beginning of string *or* a space. Add more characters between the square brackets to include them as well (e.g. `(^|[ _])` to also match underscores.

## Explanation

- `^` matches **start of string**
- `[ ]` matches **space (U+0020)** *(or any other character between `[` and `]`)*
- `(` & `)` make a **group**
- `|` between `(` & `)` means **or**

### So...

- `(^|[ ])` means a **group** which is either **start of string** *or* **space (U+0020)**

## New Regex

```
echo preg_replace("/(^|[ ])(\RT(?=\s))/", '$1{RT}', $tweet);
```

***Note:** It was mentioned by @DVK that it is poor practice to only match against start of string and a space (rather than word boundaries). Because specific characters were requested by the OP, matching by word boundaries is not technically correct. However, as @DVK did make a valid point, I'd like to mention that using `(\b)` instead of `(^|[ ])` in many occasions will provide results that fit your idea of 'correct' better (e.g. "Awesome,RT Some tweet."). Nevertheless, please keep in mind that this note was added after being accepted and is in no way part of the answer for this specific question--it is only provided to aid those that may come across this answer for a similar, but different problem.*

Comment: @DVK, first off, commas are typically followed by a space. Secondly, I made sure to mention how to add additional characters to the matching group. And last, but not least, the original poster specifically asked for how to match the beginning of the string or a space ("only allow (nothing- beginning of string) or (space) in front of 'RT'").

Comment: Absolutely correct. While it isn't *technically* the solution to the question asked, I have added a note in regards to the word boundary issue and cited you (and also mentioned it was added after the fact and is only provided as convenience for future users, but is *not* part of the answer).

Answer (score 5):

Use `\b` for [word boundary](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) matching. `\bRT\b`

Comment: Considering the reliability of the RT being as it is: uppercase, whole word...a word boundary as dvk suggests is clearly the most elegant and reliable solution.  It is even extendable to work with the @name that follows, further reducing the possibility of false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:
^\s*RT

will match any string beginning with RT or space like RT

Comment: This is wrong. He wants to match on start of string and not necessarily end of string

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way you could check for a RT would be a regex to check for a RT(space)@username. That means you would have something like

```
#RT\s@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)#
```

Of course you will need to change the [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ depending on what characters are allowed in a username. Considering it's a tweet, twitter allows letters, numbers and underscores so this regex should work fine.