# Matching specific characters preceded by a space or nothing Regex

Tags: php, regex

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297251/regex-to-only-match-specific-characters-preceded-by-a-space-or-nothing-start-of) I am attempting the same task, however the regex given below is giving me conflicting results:

```
$text = "Jiaaah.. RT @mizter_popo";

$pattern = "/(^|[ ])(\RT(?=\s))/";

if(preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
    echo "correct";
} else {
    echo "wrong";
}
```

I am expected this to give 'correct'. Running this in a PHP script on my local server and [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) returns 'wrong'. Running the same logic [here](http://www.ruig.com/laboratorium/regex-tester) returns 'correct'? Can anyone help explain what is going on? Or maybe I am wrong to expect 'correct' to be echoed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, removing the `\` before the `RT` works on both in this specific instance:

```
$pattern = "/(^|[ ])(RT(?=\s))/";
```

It is possible the regex tester site are doing some heavy sanitisation to make sure people don't break their site, which may skew what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Perfect! I should've realised an online tester would do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a pattern which uses an assertion instead of the look-behind. There is alternation as well, but I bet that could be factored into the assertion with someone a little more REGEX talented than I...

```
$pattern = "/(^RT)|((?<=[ ])RT)/";
```

Comment: ah I hadn't thought about it from that perspective. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This code would work**

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=^|\s)RT(?=\s)/', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

but the site you mentioned not supporting this anyway.